# What exactly was the difference between Alara Kalama & uddaka rāmaputta teachings?

Tags: the-buddha, buddhas

Correct me if I am wrong.

Siddharth went to Alara Kalama, who told him to focus on his breath in order to get rid of Feelings, (Buddha achieved Alara Kalama level in 2 months), Now he told his teacher that when he is in meditation, everything is fine but on coming to ordinary state, Negative & positive Feelings again came to him.

Now Alara Kalama told him to go to uddaka rāmaputta, **What did Siddharth learn under uddaka rāmaputta ?**

Above information is seen in an indian television show "**Buddha**"
I wanna know what happened in real ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two teachers are in the [Ariyapariyesana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.026.than.html).

Alara Kalama taught to focus on '*nothingness*' and Uddaka Ramaputta taught to enter the '*dimension of neither perception nor non-perception*'.

Both meditations are only mental stillness & quiet and do not uproot the causes of suffering. The the '*dimension of neither perception nor non-perception*' is very close to unconsciousness. They can only bring temporary peace, which is why the Buddha rejected them. They are not freedom. The Buddha discovered true freedom is having no craving, no attachment and no self.

Comment: i feel sad, Buddha promised his wife that he will be back once he find the answers.
Though he went there but now he was not attached to her.

I don't know i am attached or not, but every sun set makes me sad.
Life of Buddha makes me sad.(for his family).

After all like everyone, buddha had to die (consciously).

I do not understand how Buddha was happy when her wife cried in front of her ?

Comment: The Pali scriptures do not mention him saying anything to his wife. They only say he left home with tears streaming down the face of his parents. The Buddha was obviously never attracted to his wife according to the scriptures. He obviously rarely if ever had sex with her since he married at 16 and had a child at 29. He must have made an arrangement with his father to bear an heir so he could leave home. His son & wife later became fully enlightened; the best thing. The Buddha saved the world. It was the most happy ending possible. You should celebrate rather than be sad.

Comment: Actually, Buddha's wife probably died while giving birth. That's probably why the Buddha sought for enlightment. André Barreau proved it in his biography of the Buddha.

Answer (score 0):

The Bodhisatta learned the perception of nothingness and later feeling of neither perception nor non-perception from his teachers, these are the highest meditative perception & feeling attainments. He later discovered the cessation principle and abided in the meditative attainment which is the cessation of perception & feeling for 7 days & 7 nights and with that entering & emerging he attained Buddhaship.