# Previous gurus or teachers of the Buddha

Tags: the-buddha

When Gautama left his palace to become an ascetic, it is said that he found some Gurus he learnt from, and left further dissatisfied. Is there any mention of that period of the Buddha's life in the texts? Or did Buddha speak about these experiences?

I got this link : http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/lifebuddha/13lbud.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is found in the [Ariya Pariyesanā Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/1.11-Ariya-Pariyesana-S-m26.pdf), [(Deva) Saṅgarava Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/10.9-Deva-Sangarava-S-m100-piya.pdf), [Mahā Saccaka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/49.4-Maha-Saccaka-S-m36-piya.pdf), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Main two teachers were **Alara Kalama** & **uddaka rāmaputta**, Alara Kalama taught to focus on 'nothingness' and Uddaka Ramaputta taught to enter the 'dimension of neither perception nor non-perception', also see [This](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/18795/9846)